# How to set a name for not null constraint in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, constraints, notnull

i tried to set names for constraints in MariaDB like i used to do in oracle but i got error.

This my code:

```
"CREATE TABLE TBLPROFILES(
ID_PROFILE INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
PROFILE_NAME VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT NN_PROFILES_PROFILE_NAME NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UQ_PROFILES_PROFILE_NAME UNIQUE (PROFILE_NAME),
CONSTRAINT PK_PROFILES_ID_PROFILE PRIMARY KEY (ID_PROFILE));"
```

This is the error:

"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server ver
sion for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT NN_PROFILES_PROFILE_NAME NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UQ_PROFILES_PROFILE_NAM' at line 3"

Answer (score 0):

There are a thousand syntax differences between Oracle and MySQL.  You *must* consult the MySQL reference manual.

```
CREATE TABLE TBLPROFILES(                       -- ok
    ID_PROFILE INT(3) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- ok
    PROFILE_NAME VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,         -- note 1
    UNIQUE (PROFILE_NAME),                      -- note 2
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_PROFILE));                  -- note 2
```

Note 1:  `NOT NULL` is not really a "constraint"; it is part of the column definition.

Note 2:  I provided a simpler syntax.  (Possibly the Oracle syntax would also work; I don't know.)

Other notes:

`INT(3)` -- the `3` is ignored unless you have `ZEROFILL`.  An `INT` is always a 32-bit number.  (I think this differes from Oracle.)

All-caps is not normally used in MySQL for table and column names.  (But it does work, and such are always case-folded.)

Disclaimer:  No, I don't know exactly how many differences there are.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation.